# Where can i translate wordpress sentences/word?

Tags: wordpress, translation

in my french version of wordpress, i have some untranslated string such as

- "Posted By"
- "Comments"
- "leave a reply" ... "name"

Where can i translate such strings please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in your active theme files, such as comments.php, index.php, page.php, etc. See if there is a .po file: [Translating WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks, i'm using an english Theme, maybe that's why some strings are in english. Thanks for your anwser